# How to get a Garou out of Death Rage?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken, rage, hunter-the-vigil

From my Storyteller, it seems as though the Death Rage is a permanent state. My question is twofold:

1) Will a Garou ever leave Death Rage naturally? Is it only by healing a certain amount of damage?

2) Can a Garou be knocked out while in Death Rage? Does he make the roll to remain conscious for having full bashing damage?

I would like to get this issue solved, my hunter has lost $15,000 due to not being able to capture werewolves alive.

Comment: As question....forsaken 1.0 or 2.0? (the rules are quite different). Or acccording to the hunter vigil 1.0 rules?

Comment: @ThomasE. The question is tagged for 1.0. Why question it? (as an aside, you know the rules update for Hunter has been out for quiet some time now? It is in the book "Mortal Remains")

Comment: Ah wasn't sure as from what I know not all know that a second new world of darkness tag exists (at least I myself overlooked it a few times)

Answer (score 4):

It depends if you the your are using the Hunter simplified werewolf rules
(Page 318-321, of Hunter the Vigil) , or the full rules from Werewolf the Forsaken.

**Hunter the Vigil (page 318)** says of Garou (it does not differentiate Garou from Death-rage, and indeed does not use those terms, but it is possible you are using them as "slang")

> She ignores wound penalties, and she does not roll
>   for unconsciousness. She cannot use complex tools, or
>   engage in complex Mental or Social tasks — instead, every turn she must either attack or move toward a visible
>   enemy. The only way to end this frenzy is to assume one
>   of her other forms.

That is basically all the rules. Which is to say 1) Yes a Garou will leave naturally, it is a voluntary action. 2) No the Garou does not roll to remain concious, which is normally taken to mean "Does not roll to remain concious when damage track is full". I would say it is your GM's call as to if that also means they are immune to say being Chloroformed.

---

If using the full rules:

**Werewolf the Forsaken Page 174** on Death Rage

> Upon entering Death Rage, a werewolf automatically assumes Gauru form
>   as a reflexive action (if he’s not already in Gauru). The usual
>   Stamina + Primal Urge limit on the number of turns spent in Gauru form
>   is ignored. The character remains in Gauru for as long as the Death
>   Rage lasts, which is normally for the duration of the scene. ... 
>   A
>   werewolf in Death Rage who has suffered a wound in one of his last
>   three Health boxes isn’t subject to wound penalties (as established
>   under “Gauru — The Wolf-Man”). He is subconsciously aware of his
>   danger, however, and is overwhelmed by the instinct to survive at all
>   costs, an instinct that takes the form of pure fear. He runs as
>   quickly as possible away from the source of the trouble ...
>
> The effects of Death Rage persist for the remainder of the scene,
>   though the Storyteller may allow an additional Resolve + Composure
>   control roll once several turns have passed or if the character’s
>   packmates try to talk him down to end the state early.

**Werewolf the Forsaken Page 171** on Garou

> In Gauru form, a werewolf ignores wound penalties to dice pools until
>   a wound is marked in his rightmost Health box. Until then, he simply
>   doesn’t register pain. Stamina rolls to remain conscious aren’t made
>   when a bashing wound is marked in a werewolf’s rightmost Health box.
>   He remains conscious automatically, collapsing only when a lethal or
>   aggravated wound is marked in that box (and the character is dying or
>   dead)

So on Q1) will the Garou exit death rage:

Yes under the conditions:

- End of Scene (usually)
- By calming down (resolve+composure) either after several turns of if pack mates try and talk down; at GM's discretion.

So the second point isn't going to help you, but you could make use of the first:
If you try to net (etc) the werewolf, and he goes full deathrage, just back off and leave (preferably at great speed so he can't pursue). Thus ending the scene. You can come back and try and ambush him again later. Though he may wreck part of the town, while you are avoiding killing him.

Note that healing damage will *not* end Death-Rage.

Q2) Can a Garou be knocked out while in Death Rage?

Not by taking full bashing damage, but by taking full lethal damage yes. So that could work out, it you attack him with lethal force til he is on full Lethal, but not full Aggravated. He will be unconscious and bleeding out.
Now to stop the werewolf bleeding out, you either need to stabalise him normally (with first aid, or magical healing), or through some other means keep him alive for 15 minutes so he can automatically heal 1 lethal.

However, even if you only put him on full lethal -- without Agg, he will take a lot of Aggravated damage as he reverts to human form when knocked out (Page 171). He looses 2  Stamina and 2 Size, which means he has 4 of his lethal boxes roll over into Agg damage.
But still with a trained medic, you should be fine.

Comment: oxi: the werewolf: 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: 1.0 IN 2.0 death rage is really different (you got hard rage and soft rage) and I don't have much experience.